# Example of educational theory not taken in account in e-learning software?

Tags: research-process, software

In some papers I read some pedagogical experts claiming that e-learning software such as Moodle, blackboard, elluminate, etc. are not good because they don't take enough of educational theory into consideration. But there is a lack of examples in those papers.

Can someone give me some example of educational theory not taken in account in e-learning software? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the best source for examples would be in the citations included in the papers you read.

Comment: @RoboKaren are you sure this is the right question you wanted to indicate as a possible duplicate?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't see at all how the question asked above look like to the one pointed by the link given above. They are totally two different questions having absolutely nothing in common.

Comment: Sorry, wrong flag.

Comment: Measuring learning is hard. LMS help automate part of a pedagogy, but they don't provide enough high level features to add value to instructors at a learning level. An analogy might be a word processor, even with grammar and spelling features, won't add much value to the dimension of writing a good research paper. In Moodle, for example, there is no feature to help you create good distractors (common misconception answers) in multiple choice questions, since it's curriculum- or even cultural-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moodle and Blackboard & co are learning management systems, not e-learning software that is sometimes (but not always) built into such an LMS. There is indeed a lack of educational theory behind many e-learning units, for example, the learning goals are not clearly defined, the target group is not specified, the evaluation of the learning goals (if stated) does not actually match, etc. And there are many side issues (hidden curricula, usability, etc).

Comment: Playing Devil's advocate: isn't software just a tool?  What is the educational value of a dry erase board, or a desk?  Nothing without the teacher to write on it and the students to sit in them.  Seems the e-learning platforms are just that -- platforms.  It's up to the school or department or instructor to put them to good and proper use.

Comment: Moodle's Workshop activity tries hard to automate some theory. But its usability is terrible, and there's little documentation on how to design the content of a Workshop to add pedagogical value.